# Check if Boolean is True - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

Trying to figure out the syntax here. I have the following in my index action for my controller

```
@advertiser.experiments.where(:archive == "true")
```

Obviously this syntax is incorrect. I've tried a million iterations of the above syntax, but cannot figure it out.

archive is a Boolean and is set by a checkbox in my form. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@advertiser.experiments.where(archive: true)`

Comment: This did it. Thanks!